# An Error when trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am new at this so please bear with me. As of late I have been getting an error every once in a while when trying to connect to SQL Server. This SQL Server and all its contents and databases live on my computer exclusively.

I cannot think of anything that has changed to cause this problem. I do remember however that this problem never occurred before the most recent update. I run Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Usually I just turn off my computer and then come back in 5 minutes or keep trying to connect again and again till it works.

[image: the error]

**UPDATE**

I have managed to resolve this issue on my own by once again turning off and on my computer and trying to connect to SQL Server once again. While this solution does work, it isn't very professional. I feel like there should be a better way.

In response to Tanner's suggestion I have clicked on windows but could not find the services tab. Perhaps windows is located elsewhere? Also I rarely let my computer hibernate or go to sleep and yet the problem happens anyway. Below is a screenshot of me attempting your suggested solution.

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your SQL Server service isn't running for some reason when you can't connect. Restarting your PC is simply starting the service as normal. I sometimes experience this when my machine comes out of sleep/hibernate mode.

If you navigate to `Windows > Services > SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`, and start the service if it's not running you should be able to connect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is your sql server running? I remember that i had the problem that my server kept shutting itself down every time i turn my pc to sleep mode and i had to start it up manualy.

Comment: There don't seem to be multiple instances of it running.

Comment: turning off my computer and trying again is what I would do to get it to work again. I don't think that is causing the problem. Could be wrong though.